# Windows Explorer cannot access SharePoint until web login occurs

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, internet-explorer, sharepoint

I can open a SharePoint site in Windows Explorer by navigating to the site using Internet Explorer and clicking `Library > Open with Explorer`. Then, I can add the site to my Windows Explorer Favorites for easy access. I can access the site using Windows Explorer until I reboot my computer. After a reboot, clicking the Windows Explorer Favorite errors: "Windows cannot access [SharePoint directory]". If I reopen the site in Internet Explorer and click `Library > Open with Explorer` again, the Windows Explorer Favorite will work.

I followed the steps here to allow automatic login for Internet Explorer for the SharePoint site with no luck:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd572939(v=office.13).aspx

How can I use a Windows Explorer Favorite pointed at a SharePoint site without first having to open it using Internet Explorer?

Comment: might need to login to the sharepoint 1st as most sharepoints require authentication, if you map the directory as a drive on your computer you can set it to log you in with whatever credentials you need, thus removing the need to login via a browser

Answer (score 1):

The answer is you cannot, but you can get close. This is a well known problem that I have had to tackle for many years in my professional life, even with the most recent SharePoint revision within Office 365. In-order to use SharePoint via Windows Explorer the following needs to be true:

- Your Web Client Windows service needs to be started and the startup type should be set to automatic.
- The SharePoint site in question needs to be added to the trusted sites list within Internet Explorer.
- You need tick the box that says "Remember me" on the SharePoint logon page (if possible), this will usually mean that the SharePoint connection will hold for quite a while.
- You will still probably need to launch SharePoint via Internet Explorer to re-authenticate. If your password is remembered and you're kept signed in then the process is quite seamless.

There are 3rd party apps that will re-map your drives upon login using your SharePoint credentials, although I am yet to find one that is free. Another alternative is to use SharePoint workspace.